# dragging from solution explorer then dropping into a wpf-based ToolWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, vsix, solution-explorer

I am trying to implement a functionality which enables drag and drop of code files from solution explorer, and when dropped into my ToolWindow, I can get the file's path to handle it in my way.

I added AllowDrop attribute to the UserControl that I am dropping the item onto, and set it to true, but it seems I cannot drop an item onto the ToolWindow. (when the cursor hovers over the ToolWindow, the cursor changes to a black circle with diagonal cross through)

Why is this happening? and how can this problem be solved?

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: I have the same question asked on msdn forum, and details are there. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d63d2e4a-59fe-4df0-9cbf-bfe5264f890a/dragging-from-solution-explorer-then-dropping-into-a-wpfbased-toolwindow?forum=wpf

Comment: Try this, create a very small sample project that gets drag and drop to work outside of VSIX solution, once that is working then you can compare that to current code inside VSIX.  I'm guessing this is a WPF issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added AllowDrop="true" to the xml and 
handled the events DragEnter and DragOver.

```
    private void myListView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        myListView.Focus();
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        Debug.Print("DragOver reached");
    }

    private void myListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        Debug.Print("DragOver reached");
    }
```

The events were reached but the mouse cursor still showed the circle (No drop allowed) 
And than i did a small change, i added the line 
e.Handled = true; ;)
**Now it works. :)**

```
    private void myListView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        e.Handled = true;
        Debug.Print("DragOver reached\n");
    }

    private void myListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        e.Handled = true;
        Debug.Print("DragOver reached\n");
    }
```